# How can I stringify (JSON) a table when I have a <select> dropdown in the table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am trying to use JSON to pull what is selected in a table and populate an array which I can then push into a sharepoint list. What I'm getting at the moment pulls all data from the select list.

I have the following function:

> Script:

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#clicker').on('click', function (e) {
             var tableToObj = function (table) {
                 var trs = table.rows,
                 trl = trs.length,
                 i = 0,
                 j = 0,
                 keys = [],
                 obj, ret = [];
                 for (; i < trl; i++) {
                     if (i == 0) {
                         for (; j < trs[i].children.length; j++) {
                             keys.push(trs[i].children[j].innerHTML);
                         }
                     } else {
                         obj = {};
                         for (j = 0; j < trs[i].children.length; j++) {
                             obj[keys[j]] = trs[i].children[j].innerHTML;
                         }
                         ret.push(obj);
                     }
                 }
                 return ret;
             };
             document.getElementById('r').innerHTML =  JSON.stringify(tableToObj(document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0]));
         });
     });
</script>
```

> HTML

```
 <table>
    <tr><td>id</td><td><select><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select></td><td>value2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>0</td><td>1.5</td><td>2.15</td></tr>
</table>
<button id="clicker">Button</button>
<br />
Result:
<div id="r"></div>
```

Edit: Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/naLfud1f/3/

The output I am expecting is for it to pick up the value I choose in the select box, rather than both of them. e.g.

```
[{"id":"0","":"0","2":"0"},{"id":"0","":"1.5","2":"2.15"}]
```

or

```
[{"id":"0","":"0","1":"0"},{"id":"0","":"1.5","1":"2.15"}]
```

rather than both 1 and 2

Comment: What output are you expecting exactly?

Comment: Unfortunately the format you've got there is invalid - you can't have an empty string as the key of an object.

Comment: Hi Rory, yes you are correct. I won't have any empty strings. This is just a demo piece I made separately. None of the strings will be empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding an if statement in one of the loops...

```
var sel = $(trs[i].children[j]).find("select");
if (sel.length == 0) {
    keys.push(trs[i].children[j].innerHTML);
} else {
    keys.push(sel.val());
}
```

It generates this result:

```
[{"1":"0","id":"0","value2":"0"},
 {"1":"1.5","id":"0","value2":"2.15"}]
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/naLfud1f/6/). Is that what you want ?

Comment: Yes, I had something like that originally but must have had an error somewhere!

Comment: Hi, this isn't actually exactly working as I thought it would. Should I just  post a new question? I dont really like asking multiple questions about the same thing

Comment: Hi, I actually did get it working thanks! Now I'm just trying to debug other issues. cheers

Comment: If you felt like throwing me one last bone, My question at the moment is sitting here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37188954/how-can-i-get-dynamic-table-inputs-to-go-into-array?noredirect=1#comment61911242_37188954  I havent done something like this in a while so my mistakes are probably all amateur