# How can I get dynamic table inputs to go into array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I already have it working for the  inputs, now I think it's just stupid errors that I've failed to notice.

My Script looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#clicker').on('click', function (e) {
            var tableToObj = function (table) {
                var trs = table.rows,
    trl = trs.length,
    i = 0,
    j = 0,
    keys = [],
    obj, ret = [];




                for (; i < trl; i++) {
                    if (i == 0) {

                        for (; j < trs[i].children.length; j++) {

                            var sel = $(trs[i].children[j]).find("select");
                            if (sel.length == 0) {
                                keys.push(trs[i].children[j].innerHTML);
                            } else {
                                keys.push(sel.find('option:selected').val()); //all select works perfectly
                            }

                            var input = $(trs[i].children[j]).find("input"); //here I'm trying to find the input. This is where it stops working
                            if (input.length == 0) {
                                keys.push(trs[i].children[j].innerHTML);
                            } else {
                                keys.push(trs[i].childen[j].innerHTML);
                            }

                        }

                    } else {

                        obj = {};
                        for (j = 0; j < trs[i].children.length; j++) {  //this works
                            var sel = $(trs[i].children[j]).find("select");
                            if (sel.length == 0) {
                                obj[keys[j]] = trs[i].children[j].innerHTML;
                            } else {
                                obj[keys[j]] = sel.find('option:selected').val();
                            }

                            var input = trs.getElementsByTagName("input");  //below does not work
                            if (input.length == 0) {
                                obj[keys[j]] = trs[i].children[j].innerHTML;
                            } else {
                                obj[keys[j]] = input.find('text').val();
                            }



                            /* 
                            for (j < input.length; j++) {
                            data.push(input[j].id);
                            } 
                            */
                        }





                        ret.push(obj);
                    }

                }

                return ret;
            };

            document.getElementById('r').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(tableToObj(document.getElementById('myTable')));


        });


    });
```

Here's the less relevant HTML: (included just to see where I'm pulling from)

```
<table id="myTable">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​FirstColumn</th>
         <th>SecondColumn</th>
         <th>ThirdColumn</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td> 
            <select><option value="tr1">tr1</option><option value="tr2">tr2</option><option value="tr3">tr3</option><option value="tr4">tr4</option></select></td>
         <td>1</td>
         <td> 
            <select><option value="tr1">tr1</option><option value="tr2">tr2</option><option value="tr3">tr3</option></select></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td>
         </td>
         <td> 
            <select><option value="tr1">tr1</option><option value="tr2">tr2</option><option value="tr3">tr3</option><option value="tr4">tr4</option></select></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><input type="text" /></td>
         <td><input type="text" />
         </td>
         <td> 
            <select><option value="tr1">tr1</option><option value="tr2">tr2</option><option value="tr3">tr3</option></select></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
         <input type="text" /></td>
         <td><input type="text" /></td>
         <td><input type="text" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><input type="text" /></td>
         <td><input type="text" /></td>
         <td> 
            <select><option value="tr1">tr1</option><option value="tr2">tr2</option><option value="tr3">tr3</option></select></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>​​
```

EDIT: I have since trs[i] in where it was meant to be

Comment: you use a lot of `input`s and `select`s, have you got a `form` as parent? If yes, why you don't use the default jqery serializer for that? like `$('myForm').serialize()`

Comment: What is `#clicker` element here?

Comment: Why not use `.getElementsByTagName('td')`, loop through that and reference your inputs using `.children[0]` seeing as they are all your first elements within their respective parent elements (which also happen to be td)? Then you could use `.tagName` of the child elements to determine which subroutine to perform in order to extract the data. It's trivial from there to figure out how to make it work regardless of where the child element is. You can simply do another `.getElementsByTagName('*')` and loop through that with a switch statement on the `.tagName`.

Comment: I left it out, sorry! #Clicker is the button

Comment: Patrick, I do have a form in my actual page. This is just an extract to show the issue

Answer (score 0):

You were trying to use `getElementByTagName`on array of elements and hence you should have used `index` in `var input = trs[i].getElementsByTagName("input");` instead you were doing var `input = trs.getElementsByTagName("input");`

**A side note -** Please do not combine `javascript` and `jquery`. When you have plugin included, please use its features too.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#clicker').on('click', function(e) {
         var tableToObj = function(table) {
             var trs = table.rows,
                 trl = trs.length,
                 i = 0,
                 j = 0,
                 keys = [],
                 obj, ret = [];
             for (; i < trl; i++) {
                 if (i == 0) {
                     for (; j < trs[i].children.length; j++) {
                         var sel = $(trs[i].children[j]).find("select");
                         if (sel.length == 0) {
keys.push(trs[i].children[j].innerHTML);
                         } else {
keys.push(sel.find('option:selected').val()); //all select works perfectly
                         }
                         var input = $(trs[i].children[j]).find("input"); //here I'm trying to find the input. This is where it stops working
                         if (input.length == 0) {
keys.push(trs[i].children[j].innerHTML);
                         } else {
keys.push(trs[i].childen[j].innerHTML);
                         }
                     }

                 } else {
                     obj = {};
                     for (j = 0; j < trs[i].children.length; j++) { //this works
                         var sel = $(trs[i].children[j]).find("select");
                         if (sel.length == 0) {
                             obj[keys[j]] = trs[i].children[j].innerHTML;
                         } else {
                             obj[keys[j]] = sel.find('option:selected').val();
                         }
                         var input = trs[i].getElementsByTagName("input"); //below does not work
                         if (input.length == 0) {
                             obj[keys[j]] = trs[i].children[j].innerHTML;
                         } else {
                             obj[keys[j]] = input.value;
                         }
                     }
                     ret.push(obj);
                 }

             }
             return ret;
         };

         document.getElementById('r').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(tableToObj(document.getElementById('myTable')));
     });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>FirstColumn</th>
            <th>SecondColumn</th>
            <th>ThirdColumn</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select>
                    <option value="tr1">tr1</option>
                    <option value="tr2">tr2</option>
                    <option value="tr3">tr3</option>
                    <option value="tr4">tr4</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>
                <select>
                    <option value="tr1">tr1</option>
                    <option value="tr2">tr2</option>
                    <option value="tr3">tr3</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select>
                    <option value="tr1">tr1</option>
                    <option value="tr2">tr2</option>
                    <option value="tr3">tr3</option>
                    <option value="tr4">tr4</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <select>
                    <option value="tr1">tr1</option>
                    <option value="tr2">tr2</option>
                    <option value="tr3">tr3</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <select>
                    <option value="tr1">tr1</option>
                    <option value="tr2">tr2</option>
                    <option value="tr3">tr3</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" id="clicker" value="click" />
<div id="r">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have updated it with that but it's still not working. Must be other issues too

Comment: yeah I keep getting undefined is not a function anywhere input is mentioned

Comment: I get the following in the output: [{"​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​FirstColumn":"1","SecondColumn":" \n  "},{"​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​FirstColumn":"\n ","SecondColumn":" \n  "},{},{},{}] so its still not picking up the input

Comment: @Stacker.. Correct me if am wrong.. You want to fetch all the input values and `selected options` right?